# what is the "written out" equivalent of a ternary assignment?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, conditional-operator

I have a struct that is **non-default-constructibe**.
I want to assign different values to an object of that struct depending on a condition.
Since the struct is non-default-constructibe, it is not possible to declare an unitialized object of it.
However, it is possible to do that with a ternary:

```
struct foo {
    foo(int a);
};

foo generateFoo1() {
    return foo(1);
}

foo generateFoo2() {
    return foo(2);
}

int main() {
    bool test = false;

    //compiles fine
    foo f = test ? generateFoo1() : generateFoo2();

    //the following does not compile
    foo f2;
    if(test) {
        f2 = generateFoo1();
    }else {
        f2 = generateFoo2();
    }
}
```

What would be a "written out" equivalent of the ternary assignment?
I have simplicity in mind and the ternary is a thorn in my eye. I would like to keep it as clean/readable as possible.

Comment: `foo f = [=]{ if (test) return generateFoo1(); return generateFoo2(); }();`

Comment: You can use a lambda function as an approximation, but it is not going to be any neater than the conditional operator.

Comment: The conditional operator *is* the clean/readable option.

Comment: If readability is the aim, then simply format the ternary to be spread over multiple lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a factory function can help you out here.  Using

```
foo make_foo(bool test)
{
    if (test)
        return generateFoo1();
    else
        return generateFoo2();
}
```

lets you have code like

```
foo f = make_foo(test);
```