# Pointing to an object that's going out of scope

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

I want to allocate an object of type `custom_type_t` (`operator=` is not available for this `custom_type_t` and I'm unable to modify that part of the codebase) depending on whether a condition is met and, if it's not met, that object should not be created at all.

I was initially thinking I could do:

```
// create the object even if it's not needed
custom_type_t object; // just use their default constructor which hopefully isn't expensive

if (condition_met) {
  object = custom_type_t(constructor arguments);
}
```

However, this isn't possible because there's no `operator=`.

I'm wondering if there's a way in which I can do something like the following:

```
int* custom_type_t ptr;
if (condition_met) {
  custom_type_t object = custom_type_t(constructor arguments);
  ptr = &custom_type_t;
} // but object may go out of scope here, so ptr may end up pointing to garbage

// ptr will be used later on if condition_met == true
```

But I need to have `object` actually remain valid so `ptr` doesn't point to garbage?

Comment: Maybe a `std::unique_ptr<custom_type_t>` or `std::optional<custom_type_t>` could help you out, but consider whether or not it is possible to at least implement the move assignement operator `custom_type_t::operator=(custom_type_t &&)`. It is rare that it is actually impossible to implement it.

Comment: Why don’t you want to just use dynamic allocation with `new` (or, better yet, something like `make_unique` for `unique_ptr`)?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The codebase that introduces `custom_type_t` is a third party code base, and I don't think I'm allowed to modify it to suit my purpose

Comment: Adding a layer of abstraction will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70508229/4342498

Comment: @Sneftel I don't think I understand how that would work here? Wouldn't I run into the same problem, i.e., the `unique_ptr` will go out of scope?

Comment: No, the unique_ptr would be your `ptr`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I think that's going to be my backup option, but I may just end up doing that. There will be some minor duplication between the `generateFoo`s

Comment: @Sneftel Oh yeah I see what you're saying now. I forget that smart pointers does everything dynamically and not statically. I think that approach could work too. This part that I'm implementing is performance-focused, so I'm a bit concerned with performance but I'll try some profiling to see.

Comment: @Sneftel Doesn't `unique_ptr` have to be assigned at initialization? I don't think I can do `ptr = make_shared<custom_type_t>(constructor args)` inside the `if` after declaring `std::unique_ptr<custom_type_t>` before entering the `if`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. And you can't use `make_shared` because you need to use `make_unique` to make a `unique_ptr`. But you can use `shared_ptr` instead if you want. Or just use raw pointers. Really, you have a ton of options here, you just need to stop trying to stack-allocate the object.

Comment: (Or, if you demand stack_allocation, use `std::optional` like François suggested.)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux With the `std::unique_ptr<custom_type_t> object` approach, wouldn't I run into the same issue with no `operator=` when I try to do `object = custom_type_t(constructor arguments)`?

Comment: @roulette01 For that approach you would need to dynamically create the `custom_type_t` with `std::make_unique<custom_type_t>`. Then you wouldn't copy or move the object, you would be manipulating a pointer to it. This solution is analogous to using a pointer and `new`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ah I see. That makes sense

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Is there a way to call the constructor (without having to go through `operator=`) for `custom_type_t` after declaring `std::optional<custom_type_t> object`? It doesn't seem there would be

Comment: @roulette01 Look at [`std::optional<T>::emplace(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/emplace).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ah yes. It seems that function will clear the object and then reconstruct it. I just tested it, and it seems to work. With `emplace`, it seems we can avoid dynamic allocation to solve this issue?

Comment: @roulette01 Maybe in this example, but you're still stuck with a non-moveable `optional` now. So you need to finish using it before the function returns. At least with a `unique_ptr` you can move it somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Your problems/confusion seem to lie in separating the idea of *creating* an object from that of explicitly *declaring* that object. You can quite easily (conditionally) create your object, and subsequently use it, by *just* declaring a pointer to it.

Using a simple 'raw' pointer, something like this (for the sake of the example, I have assumed that two `int` values are required for the constructor arguments):

```cpp
void function()
{
    custom_type_t* pObject = nullptr;
    if (condition_met) {
        pObject = new custom_type_t(42, -9);
    }
    // ...

    delete pObject; // If still nullptr, no problem - does nothing.
}
```

Or, better, using a smart pointer:

```cpp
void function()
{
    std::unique_ptr<custom_type_t> pObject;
    if (condition_met) {
        pObject = std::make_unique<custom_type_t>(42, -9);
    }
    //...

    // "pObject" is automagically freed when this function returns.
}
```

In either of the above cases, you can use `*pObject` in expressions where you would otherwise use `object`, and you can use `pObject->memberFunc()` instead of `object.memberFunc()`.